# Diesel getting into engine oil since cambelt change

Tags: oil, vw, diesel, contamination

Got my VW Touran cambelt water pump serviced recently (4-5 weeks ago). Oil and filter were changes then too

Today, Noticed that the oil level was about 8mm higher than max on dip stick. Oil was very thin and smelled like diesel.

Have been booked in again on Friday and advised not to drive the car

Any thoughts? Very worried :(

Comment: Yes, injectors failed - delivering too much fuel. As advised, don't drive it.

Comment: Car does not misfire , not that I can notice at least. Could this be timing related?

Comment: Gave you my opinion, not wanting a discussion, do as you wish.

Comment: Sorry, did not mean to sound rude. Thanks for your insights

Comment: It is possibly just the injector seats that are leaking.  This thread may help - https://www.volkswagenforum.co.uk/threads/2005-touran-1-9-tdi-diesel-leaking-into-engine-oil-starting-issues-w-75-fuel.32929/

Comment: By the way, welcome.  You were not being rude.

Comment: Thanks! Any idea if tandem pump is connected to the cambelt?

Comment: Agree with not driving it, but do remember ... diesel fuel is actually an oil. While it won't give the protection of regular engine oil, it does provide lubrication. It definitely needs to get fixed, but I doubt the driving you have done with it will have caused much if any long term problems for the engine.

Comment: Thanks Paulster2. So, it's just coincidence that this happened soon after the cam belt/oil/filter service. All online posts suggest it to be tandem pump or injector related issue. On closer inspection of the tandem pump just through the bay, I don't see any oil leaks etc.  So not quite sure. Have been booked it for Friday. Hope it's not anything major :( Car was excellent before the cam change

Comment: Update: I smelled the oil and compared with my other car. It smelled very very similar and does not smell like diesel at all.  So, looks like it's just a matter of over fill of oil.  Question - does oil become thinner in summer and so increase in volume???